# How to I pass an object in the RequestBody while testing the API of a Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to test the API of a Spring Boot application, without using `MockMvc` or `Mockito`. I am having trouble setting up the entity for the http post.  It seems easy when the entity is a mere String, but it harder when the request involves a class.

The Controller has this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dale/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<List<DaleSearchReturn>> 
 earchDale(@RequestBody MasterBox tlsSearchObj) {
```

So I somehow need to place a MasterBox object in the request body.  This is what I've tried in my @TEST code:

```
MasterBox masterBox = new MasterBox ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7") ;

HttpEntity<MasterBox> entity = new HttpEntity<>(masterBox);
        
HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.create("POST")
    .setUri("http://localhost:8080/dale_service/dale/search")
    .setEntity(entity).build();

// When
HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request);
```

It gives the following error on the .setEntity line...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.http.HttpEntity cannot be cast to org.apache.http.HttpEntity
    at TestAPI.givenBox_then200IsReceived(TestAPI.java:48)
```

My imports are:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
//import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;

import com.ulalaunch.pcplan.models.MasterBox;
```

Comment: Please show the code of TestAPI

Comment: The error tells you **exactly** what is wrong with your code. `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.http.HttpEntity cannot be cast to org.apache.http.HttpEntity`. You are using the wrong `HttpEntity`, you must use the Apache HTTP one NOT the Spring one. .